# DRF to return items inside data attr of json instead of array

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

What is the best approach to get a result of my endpoint serialized as:

```
{
  status: 200,
  meta: {
    "name": "foo",
    "total": 666
  },
  data: [
     {item1},
     {item2},
     {item3},
     ...with the pagination affecting this array
  ]
}
```

By default I get:

```
[
  {item1},
  {item2},
  {item3},
  ...with pagination
]
```

I was able to get a result close to what I want(missing pagination) but I believe it is not the best approach. My serializer was as follows:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
  meta = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
  data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

  def get_status(self, obj):
    return status.HTTP_200_OK

  def get_meta(self, obj):
    summary = {
      "name": obj.name,
        "total": obj.user.device_set.count()
    }
    return summary

  def get_data(self, obj):
    devices = obj.user.device_set.all()
    return DeviceListSerializer(devices, many=True).data

  class Meta:
    model = Device
    fields = ('status', 'meta', 'data')
```

Comment: I got this package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangorestframework-jsonapi suggested on Django IRC channel for doing it but need to understand better how it works.

Answer (score 0):

*Its reach you near your response you get..*

```
response_dic = {}
response_dic['status_code'] = status_code
if settings.HTTP_USER_ERROR == status_code:
    response_dic['error'] = response
elif response:
    response_dic['data'] = data
    response_dic['meta'] = meta
return response_dic
```

Comment: but this way you there is no pagination right? or I would have to control the pagination somewhat manually